# Reflection in Java: How do I create objects of different types with the same name?

Tags: java, caching, reflection

I am writing an auto-grader for my students code. Each student class is named the same thing (Selection). They are all in the same folder. I am trying to figure out how to reset the object so that when I create a new one, it actually uses the new one.

Things I've tried:

- Deleting the original .class file, and recompiling
- writing another class that I compile each time (testFile1.java compiles and calls testFile2.java, which actually creates each Selection object).

The problem seems to be that java caches the Selection class object, so that each time I run it, it uses the first Selection class, instead of the newly compiled one.

My question is: How do I reset java to get rid of the caching of a class in java, so that when I compile another file with the same name, it will actually use the new object type?

Comment: "The Selection class is a I am trying to figure out how to..." Did some words fall out of your question and onto the floor?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what your problem is. When you compile a class, it's not being updated? Why does each student have a class, and they're all named the same thing? I'm pretty confused

Comment: This particular problem is probably best solved with scripting -- have your scripts create a temp folder, copy in your driver and the  student's submission and then execute it.  Since new programmers especially are prone to do bizarre things you wouldn't want one of them accidentally (or maliciously) affecting the next students' results by changing System.out, for example.

Comment: How do you have multiple classes with the same name in the same directory? In any sane setup, that shouldn't work. You should almost definitely use separate subdirectories, in a way such as the one @Gus suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you put them in different folders, or into a temporary folder if you are processing them one at a time.

If you want to load a new version of a class without restarting your JVM, you have to put the classes into a different ClassLoader.

However, if one student does something hacky they can prevent other students code from running.  The best way to avoid this is to run each substitution in it's own JVM to avoid contamination.

For example, I can change the `(Integer) 0` to be equals to `(Integer) 1` or change "Hello" to print "G'Day", imagine what you can do. ;)